# GAE: how do I query for an item that is referenced in a specific document?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have `City` -> `District` and I need to find the `District` with a specified `name` in the specified `City`, if any.

The code:

```
class City(ndb.Model):
    districts = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=District, repeated=True)

class District(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you want the specific City record which its district has a name `'Foo'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could probably arrange your schema to be more efficient for this task -- e.g, make the city an ancestor of the district, use the city name or other unique city id, followed by the district name, in the district entity key, or de-normalize the schema so that each district redundantly records its city for speed of searching.

However, I imagine you may have other complications that stand in the way of any of these optimizations.  If performance is satisfactory for you,

```
def fetch_district_in_city(city, district_name):
    query = District.query(ndb.AND(District.name == district_name,
                                   District.key.IN(city.districts)))
    return query.fetch()
```

might work decently well -- it returns a list that's empty if no district of that name is in that city, otherwise it presumably has a single item (assuming district names within a city are unique).

The reason I don't consider this to be likely to be fully satisfactory (compared with the optimization alternatives I mention above) is that the `IN` method "explodes" to a lot of `OR` and `==` checks, as documented at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#neq_and_in , for cities that have a lot of districts.  So your app's performance might perhaps suffer, and the amount of work it's doing "behind the curtains" for what would be very lightweight with any of the above-mentioned optimizations (esp. the one relying on the key, very fast & light...).

Comment: great stuff, I don't even fully understand what OP exactly wants.

Comment: @Anzel I think he wants the district entity, given the name and city entity (of course there will be other properties in both entities, OP's showing just the skeleton).

Comment: Thanks @AlexMartelli, yes I understand it once I see your query :)

Comment: There's not that many districts in a city, and it's only run once about a day as a batch job so the performance should be good enough. In normal usage we always look for districts in a given city, so that's what the structure is optimized for.

Comment: @FilipHaglund, great, that's why I offered a solution for your schema as-is, as well as mentioning various possible optimizations (I'm sure the set of cities and districts varies seldom, so de-normalizing with each district also referring to its city would have very little cost, for example -- but if you don't need the speed boost, so much the better!).